# Ubuntu startup Programs like vbox Headless, luadch and changing metric on network

Tags: startup, autostart

i am having a bit trouble with autostarting programs, since i reinstalled my Server from 16.04 to 20.04.

first one i tried to use rc.conf -> not working and crontab -e with "@reboot start something" also not working.

before that reinstall, so on the old system i was using init.d skripts like this one for start a VirtualBox VM as a different user:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vbox

#Edit these variables!
VMUSER=vbox
VMNAME="nas8"
BASEFOLDER=/home/vbox/VMs/backups/

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting VirtualBox VM..."
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage startvm "$VMNAME" --type headless
        ;;
    reset)
        echo "Resetting VirtualBox VM..."
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage controlvm "$VMNAME" reset
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Saving state of Virtualbox VM..."
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage controlvm "$VMNAME" savestate
        ;;
    shutdown)
        echo "Shutting down Virtualbox VM..."
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage controlvm "$VMNAME" acpipowerbutton
        ;;
    status)
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage list vms -l | grep -e ^"$VMNAME": -e ^State | sed s/\ \ //g | cut -d: -f2-
        ;;
    backup)
        echo ""
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage controlvm "$VMNAME" acpipowerbutton

        echo "Waiting for VM "$VMNAME" to poweroff..."
        until $(sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage showvminfo --machinereadable "$VMNAME" | grep -q ^VMState=.poweroff.)
        do
          sleep 1
        done

        FILENAME=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d-%T")
        echo "Backing up Virtualbox VM to '$BASEFOLDER$FILENAME'..."
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage clonevm "$VMNAME" --options keepallmacs --name $FILENAME --basefolder $BASEFOLDER

        echo "Restarting VirtualBox VM..."
        sudo -H -u $VMUSER VBoxManage startvm "$VMNAME" --type headless
        echo ""
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: sudo service vbox {start|stop|status|shutdown|reset|backup}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

But even with this "update rc vbox defaults" thing - it is not working. When the System is up - i can write /etc/init.d/vbox start and it works! But not automated....
other skript thats not working anymore is luadch:

```
!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/luadch
# version 0.4.2 2016-02-09 (YYYY-MM-DD)
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: luadch
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs screen-cleanup
# Required-Stop:  $local_fs $remote_fs
# Should-Start:   $network
# Should-Stop:    $network
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description:    luadch server
# Description:    Starts the luadch server
### END INIT INFO

### Hier den Pfad zur Hubsoftware angeben
PATH="/home/dc/Luadch-2.21-Linux-x64"

# Ab hier nichts mehr aendern!
cd $PATH
case $1 in
    start)
        /usr/bin/screen -h 1024 -dmS luadch sudo -H -u dc /home/dc/Luadch-2.21-Linux-x64/luadch
    ;;
    stop)
        killall luadch
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 [start|stop]"
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

so else, causing on two Networks i need to give one adapter the primary interface. route shows up this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    200    0        0 enp6s0
192.168.n1.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
fritz.box       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.n2.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     200    0        0 enp6s0
fritz.box       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    200    0        0 enp6s0
```

without changing the metric, the Primary adapter is the wrong one for my Setup. That is a 10 gbit ASUS PCIe Card.
i am fine with the use of

```
ifmetric enp6s0 200
```

but i also need this to be run in or after boot up.

Hope this is not to much in one Question here an someone has the Time to help me with this.

Comment: Consider migrating those various startup scripts to use systemd services and targets.

Comment: Can you relate a goot How to or Article for it?